# Windows server 2012 R2, Null route

Tags: windows, routing, windows-server-2012, routing-table

I am trying to add a null route to send traffic destined to a particular resource to a non-existent address to simulate a failure.

```
PS C:\Users\Owner> route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 10...00 05 9a 3c 7a 00 ......Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Virtual Miniport Adapter for Windows x64
 29...02 00 4c 4f 4f 50 ......Npcap Loopback Adapter
 25...00 ff d9 46 d7 15 ......VMware SSL VPN-Plus Client Adapter
 23...34 02 86 ef 17 3e ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) #2
 22...34 02 86 ef 17 3b ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
 21...36 02 86 ef 17 3a ......Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter #2
 19...34 02 86 ef 17 3a ......Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 #2
 18...34 e6 d7 83 b2 be ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM #2
 15...00 05 9a 3c 78 00 ......Cisco Systems VPN Adapter for 64-bit Windows
 16...00 50 56 c0 00 01 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
 17...00 50 56 c0 00 08 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
  7...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 11...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #6
 26...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #7
 30...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #10
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.9     10
      172.24.16.0    255.255.252.0    192.168.237.1    192.168.237.8      2
      172.24.32.0    255.255.252.0    192.168.237.1    192.168.237.8      2
      172.24.48.0    255.255.252.0    192.168.237.1    192.168.237.8      2
      172.24.64.0    255.255.252.0    192.168.237.1    192.168.237.8      2
      172.24.96.0    255.255.252.0    192.168.237.1    192.168.237.8      2
     172.24.112.0    255.255.252.0    192.168.237.1    192.168.237.8      2
     172.24.120.0    255.255.252.0    192.168.237.1    192.168.237.8      2
     172.24.128.0    255.255.252.0    192.168.237.1    192.168.237.8      2
      192.168.1.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.9     11
   212.64.157.210  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.9     11
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 10     11 ::/0                     On-link
 10    266 fe80::/64                On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

I  am now adding a route to redirect traffic destined for the 172.24.48.10/32 network to a non-existent IP on our local network

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> route add 172.24.48.10 mask 255.255.255.255 
192.168.100.245 metric 1
 OK!
```

This doesn't seem to work, as i can still ping the particular address above and receive replies from the ip. Could you help me acheive what i am trying to do here and where this approach is going wrong? thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure routes for hosts (i.e. subnet mask of all 255) must point to an IP that's in the same subnetwork as your server. Try using an IP that's dead, but on your local link.

Answer (score 0):

Can [this link](https://www.beaming.co.uk/knowledge-base/how-to-add-a-null-route-in-windows/) be useful?

Basically it says that using a non-existent IP was the solution in Server 2003 but that it does not work anymore for a feature called "Dead Gateway Detection".

I am using the loopback interface. Try to specify this interface (normally is the index=1).

From the link above, the command:

`route add X.X.X.X mask Y.Y.Y.Y Z.Z.Z.Z if 1 -p`

PS by the way, in the link they suggest using the Firewall when possible